# ¿Cómo agregar un grafico a mi template en HBS? (Nodejs - Express - Puppeeter)

Tags: javascript, express, chart.js, puppeteer, handlebars

necesito su ayuda porfavor

**CONTEXTO**

Resulta que estoy creando reportes desde el backend, la idea es crearlos alli y luego llamarlos desde el cliente. Hasta alli todo bien, estoy utilizando nodejs con express y para crear mis archivos .pdf utilizo puppeter ya que me lo recomendaron por su fácil integración y accesible modificación en los estilos. Para el template estoy utilizando handlebars (hbs), he podido realizar la implementación.

Pero me ha tocado tener que integrar graficas en el reporte, anteriormente nunca lo había hecho asi que me puse a investigar y leer. Al final, he escogido la libreria [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) por su amplia documentación y ejemplos que he encontrado, pero en el momento de implementarlo en mi api no ha sido tan sencillo, no sabía como hacerlo asi que pregunté y me dijeron que porque no integraba el grafico creando el HTML y una vez lo tuviera se lo pasará a handlebar, como un triple corchete para que hbs lo interprete como tal (HTML).

Así que lo hice, seguí esta respuesta que encontre en stackoverflow en ingles [Chart.js with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60170124/chart-js-with-node-js) con un poco de traductor lo que entendi es que solo concatenan la configuración del grafico y de alli se lo pase a mi template y logre mostrarlo en el pdf.

[image: grafico1]

Pero luego queria agregar plugins al grafico, pero no me dejaba, queria agregar dataLabels [chartjs-plugins-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) con una función o agregandolo como lo recomiendan en este video [How to Show Values Inside a Stacked Bar Chart in Chart JS](https://youtu.be/rH14xZm4zvw) para asi mostrar "labels" encima de las grafica que estan apiladas y aunque intente todo lo que les he mencionado, no lo pude implementar

Asi que un poco exhausta de investigar y de probar pense ¿porqué no le paso el script de una en el template? Asi que en este momento en esas estoy, pero el problema es que intente registrar funciones con ayuda de hbs pero eso tampoco me ayudo, y en este momento no puedo mostrar el grafico.

**PROBLEMA**

¿Cómo mostrar las funciones canvas en HBS?

Pensé en usar helpers algo asi para luego solo pasarselo al script {{ element myChart }}:

```
handlebars.handlebars.registerHelper('element',
        function distanceFixed(chart) {
            let c = document.createElement("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
            let ctx = c.getContext("2d")!;
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF7605";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF7605";
            ctx.rect(145, 70, 15, 15);
            ctx.fill()
            ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
            ctx.fillText(chart.dataset.data[chart.dataIndex], 147, 82, 10);
        
            ctx.stroke();
            return c
        }
```

Hacer esto no me funciono, no me lanzó un error en especifico al hacer debug. Ahora se la intente pasar en el template

```
 element: {
                        point: {
                            pointStyle: function {
                                let c = document.createElement("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
                                let ctx = c.getContext("2d")!;
                                ctx.fillStyle = "#FF7605";
                                ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF7605";
                                ctx.rect(145, 70, 15, 15);
                                ctx.fill()
                                ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                                ctx.fillText(chart.dataset.data[chart.dataIndex], 147, 82, 10);
                                ctx.stroke();
                                return c
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

**Pregunta Problema**

**¿Cómo puedo asignar funciones con elementos canva en mi template? ¿Y como puedo agregar datalabels encima de las graficas apiladas?**

**El resultado que espero conseguir:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el codigo con algunos comentarios que pueden servir para entender un poco la estructura, lamentablemente no pude hacer una Demo para ejemplificarme mejor, pero de verdad necesito ayuda para poder implementar funciones y datalabels customizados, tal vez estoy trabada porque aun me hace falta estudiar varios conceptos que me ayudaria en la integracion, pero bueno, cualquier tipo de ayuda sera agradecida!!

**CODE**

```
// mi objeto de informacion
const dataHbs = {
    apidata,
    "KpiMaxTracked": 20,
    "KpiMinTracked": 15,
    "dateReport": moment(req.query.fecha_inicio).format('DD / MMMM / YYYY'),
    "dayliWeekly": averageWeeklyHour,
    "totalWeeklyHours": averageHoursDaily,
    "averageActivityWeekly": Math.round(averageActivityWeekly / countElements),
    "totalgeneralHours": totalGeneralHours,
    "summaryStartsCounts": countStarts,
    "weeklyReachHours": Math.round(averageHoursDaily / averageWeeklyHour),
    // "canva": _htmlChat
};

// En mi controlado creo una instancia de donde obtengo el metodo con config de puppeter
// para generar el pdf y alli le paso mi objeto con la informacion a mostrar
// dataHbs es un objeto con la info a mostrar
const dateFileName = moment(req.query.fecha_inicio).format('MMMMDDYYYY');
const filename = `CIT-ReporteDiario-${dateFileName}`;
const pdfService = new PdfClass();
const pdfBuffer = await pdfService.getPdf('reporte-semanal-cuatrodias', dataHbs);
res.contentType("application/pdf");
res.send(pdfBuffer);
```

**VIEW HBS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>TRACKING</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>


  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="container-fluid mb-2">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
          <div class="h2">
            <img style="height: 4rem;" alt="" srcset="">
          </div>

          <div class="d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="h5">
              <strong>Reporte Semanal Tracking</strong>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="font-size: 12px;" class="row mt-2 mb-2">
      <div class="col">
        <table class="mt-2">
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2" style="color: #C00000;">
              WEEKLY REVIEW
            </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img style="height: 12px;" src="https://ymlabqgbnnbvyybcyqjn.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/assets-ui/icons/status-check.svg" alt="status-check">
            </td>
            <td>Arriba de {{KpiMaxTracked}} Horas</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <img style="height: 12px;" src="https://ymlabqgbnnbvyybcyqjn.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/public/assets-ui/icons/status-close.svg" alt="status-close">
            </td>
            <td>Abajo de {{KpiMinTracked}} Horas</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <table class="mt-2">
          <br>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">WEEKLY REACH HOURS</th>
            <td class="text-right" style="white-space: nowrap;"><strong>  37</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="2">% ACTIVITY </th>
            <td><strong>{{weeklyReachHours}}%</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>

    </div>
    <div style="font-size: 7px;" class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <table class="table table-sm mt-2 border-table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><strong>AREA</strong></th>
              <th><strong>NAME</strong></th>
              <th class="text-center"><strong>WEEKLY <br> HOURS</strong></th>
              <th class="text-center"><strong>WEEKLY SUMMARY HOURS</strong></th>
              <th class="text-center"><strong>% ACTIVITY</strong></th>
              <th class="text-center"><strong>% HOURS</strong></th>
              <th class="text-center"><strong>ESTRELLAS</strong></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {{#each apidata}}
            <tr>
              <td><strong>{{rolTittle}}</strong></td>
              <td style="white-space: nowrap;">{{username}}</td>
              <td class="text-center">{{three_weekly_hours}}</td>
              <td class="text-center">{{summaryHoursTrackedWeekly}}</td>
              <td class="text-center">{{percentActivityW}}</td>
              <td class="text-center">{{distanceFixed percentageHours}}</td>
              <td class="text-center">{{summaryStarts}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
          </tbody>

          <tfoot style="font-size: 8px;" class="font-weight-bold">
            <tr>
              <td style="white-space: nowrap;">
                <strong>Total general</strong>
              </td>
              <td></td>
              <td class="text-center"><strong>{{dayliWeekly}}</strong></td>
              <td class="text-center"><strong>{{totalWeeklyHours}}</strong></td>
              <td class="text-center"><strong>{{averageActivityWeekly}}</strong></td>
              <td class="text-center"><strong>{{distanceFixed totalgeneralHours}}</strong></td>
              <td class="text-center"><strong>{{summaryStartsCounts}}</strong></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    {{!--
    <div>{{{canva}}}</div> --}}

    <section class="diaperChart">
      <div>
        <canvas id="myChart" style="h-75 mb-3"></canvas>
      </div>
    </section>

  </div>

  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/91a50598c6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <script>
    let labels = [];
    let lineBar = [];
    let barHorizontal = [];
    let colbWeekly = [];

    {
      {#
        each apidata
      }
    }
    labels.push("{{username}}")
    lineBar.push("{{summaryHoursTrackedWeekly}}")
    barHorizontal.push("{{percentActivityW}}")
    colbWeekly.push("{{three_weekly_hours}}") {
        {
          /each}}

          const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
          const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'horizontalBar',
            data: {
              {
                {
                  !--labels is labels: labels--
                }
              }
              labels,
              datasets: [{
                  type: 'line',
                  label: '% ACTIVITY',
                  data: lineBar,
                  fill: false,
                  borderColor: '#FF7605',
                  borderWidth: 3
                },
                {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: 'WEEKLY SUMMARY OF HOURS',
                  data: barHorizontal,
                  backgroundColor: '#222A35',
                },
                {
                  type: 'bar',
                  label: 'HOURS',
                  data: colbWeekly,
                  backgroundColor: '#008582'
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                  anchor: 'start',
                  align: '-45',
                  clamp: true,
                  color: '#FF7605'
                }
              },
              element: {
                point: {
                  pointStyle: function {
                    let c = document.createElement("canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
                    let ctx = c.getContext("2d") !;
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF7605";
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF7605";
                    ctx.rect(145, 70, 15, 15);
                    ctx.fill()
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    ctx.fillText(chart.dataset.data[chart.dataIndex], 147, 82, 10);
                    ctx.stroke();
                    return c
                  }
                }
              },
              scales: {
                xAxis: {
                  stacked: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                  stacked: true,
                  ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                  }
                }
              },
              tittle: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Rendimiento Semanal'
              },
              legend: {
                position: 'right'
              }
            }
          });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feliz inicio de semana!

Después de estarlo intentando por durante casi tres semanas, al fin logré terminar con lo que esperaba alcanzar.

Investigando un poco descubrí, que no es una buena practica acceder al DOM como lo estaba intentando anteriormente desde el lado del servidor, así que para mejorar esto encontré que Chartjs tiene una versión de su librería para ser usada en conjunto con node: [chartjs-node-canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-node-canvas)

No requiere de jsdom y además de que permite todas la funciones de Chartjs exceptuando algunas como las animaciones (por que obviamente no serian necesarias del lado del servidor). Esta tambien tiene algunos metodos bastantes interesantes que te ayudan a obtener un buffer del grafico como tal.

Tomando en cuenta estas herramientas, decidí estructurar el reporte que necesitaba de otra manera. El siguiente grafico lo explicará por mi:

[image: estructura del código]

Lo que hago entonces es armar mi objeto de datos, en donde le paso el buffer de la imagen que genero con ayudo de la libreria que decidi implementar, paso toda esta información a mi plantilla HBS en donde hago utilidad de handlebars para desestructurar los datos y el buffer que obuve del grafico y lo convierto a base64, luego se lo paso en la plantilla con formato png. Cuando ya tengo mis datos y mi plantilla configurada justo como los necesito, llamo el método que exporta el pdf con ayuda de [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) en donde le paso el nombre de mi plantilla y el objeto de mis datos. Dandome como resultado lo siguiente

[image: resultado]

Ahora bien respondiendo las preguntas que realicé en esta publicación:

**¿Cómo puedo asignar funciones con elementos canva en mi template?**

Para asignar funciones o llamar los hooks de chartjs, no se puede acceder a los hooks del complemento desde un complemento específico dentro de la configuración de ese complemento, asi que cree mi propio complemento personalizado y en el complemento en sí puede acceder a todos los hooks.

```
const subLabels = {
            id: 'subLabels',
            afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
                const { ctx, chartArea: { left, right, top, bottom, width, height } } = chart;

                ctx.save();
                subLabelText('DEV', width / 4 * 1.5);
                subLabelText('SAC', width / 4 * 3.1);
                subLabelText('DESIGN', width / 4 * 3.7);

                function subLabelText(text, x) {
                    ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';
                    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)';
                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                    ctx.fillText(text, x + left, bottom + 144);
                    let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
                    let xCenter = (xAxis.left + xAxis.right) / 1.45;
                    let yBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
                    [xAxis.left, xCenter, xAxis.right].forEach(x => {
                        ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.moveTo(x, yBottom);
                        ctx.lineTo(x, yBottom + 110);
                        ctx.stroke();
                    });

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
                    ctx.moveTo(width / 4 * 3.45, yBottom);
                    ctx.lineTo(width / 4 * 3.45, yBottom + 110);
                    ctx.stroke();

                    ctx.restore();
                }



            }
        }

const mkChart = await canvasRenderService.renderToBuffer({
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
           
            },
            options: {
                
            },
            plugins: [subLabels]

        });
```

Si aunque los separaste te sigue dando problemas de Types, te recomiendo agregar un archivo index.d.ts en donde hagas una variable extendida de lo que necesitas, aqui hay una respuesta que lo explica mejor [Cómo usar las opciones en el complemento personalizado Chart js v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404644/how-to-use-options-in-chart-js-v3-custom-plugin/73208744#73208744)

Otro tema a tocar siempre dentro de esta pregunta, es que yo aqui necesitaba agrupar la información, lastimosamente en Chartjs aun no se puede lograr este efecto directamente con sus elementos. Sin embargo, haciendo uso de elementos Canva para dibujar sobre ello si, lo que yo hice fue agregar un AxisID y luego a traves de ese ID que nombre, darle formato a mis ejes "X" y "Y"

Les dejo una explicación amplia sobre el tema de "agrupación" o tambien conocido como "etiquetas de categoría de varios niveles" que quizás les puede servir  [Agrupación de etiquetas del eje y en varias líneas en un ChartJS con una dimensión adicional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67275805/grouping-y-axis-labels-on-multiple-lines-on-a-chartjs-with-an-extra-dimension)

**¿Y como puedo agregar datalabels encima de las graficas apiladas?**

Esto es bastante sencillo de hacer, solo tienes que hacer uso de una plugin para integrarlo [chartjs-plugin-datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) En mi caso lo que hice fue agregar a cada tipo de grafico el plugin con su configuración deseada, eso si antes de usarla debes registrarla como menciona la documentación [registrar una plugin en Chartjs](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration)

```
const canvasRenderService = new ChartJSNodeCanvas({
        width: 1100,
        height: 700,
        chartCallback: (ChartJS) => {
            ChartJS.register(require('chartjs-plugin-datalabels'))
        }
    });

     datasets: [{
                        type: 'line',
                        label: '% ACTIVITY',
                        backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
                        borderColor: '#FF7605',
                        data: lineBar,
                        datalabels: {
                            anchor: 'start',
                            align: 'center',
                            clamp: true,
                            backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
                            color: 'white',
                            font: {
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        }
          }]
```

Y eso fue todo para alcanzar mi resultado esperado, fue una amplia investigación en diferentes temas que me ayudo a aprender un poco más, y sobre todo me llevo la experiencia al aprender a hacer reportería con graficos integrados desde el lado del servidor.

**DEMO**

```js
const apidata = [{
    "id": 6430591403,
    "task_id": 110578536,
    "user_id": 854500,
    "keyboard": 872,
    "mouse": 2123,
    "input_tracked": 20149,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 20149,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T17:40:03.167232Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T11:00:24.381152Z",
    "username": "user1",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 24,
    "three_weekly_hours": 12,
    "summaryWeekly": 29149,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 2827,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 4,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 8,
    "percentageHours": 2.024236111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 2,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 8,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 2.025
  },
  {
    "id": 6418215334,
    "task_id": 111232314,
    "user_id": 1726823,
    "keyboard": 11761,
    "mouse": 35504,
    "input_tracked": 73802,
    "manual": 862,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 74664,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T14:32:20.799309Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T11:00:48.637118Z",
    "username": "user9",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 74664,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 43021,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 21,
    "percentageHours": 5.185,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 14,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 1,
    "percentActivityW": 41,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 5.1850000000000005
  },
  {
    "id": 6436683187,
    "task_id": 110916251,
    "user_id": 957963,
    "keyboard": 2050,
    "mouse": 5530,
    "input_tracked": 13478,
    "manual": 1181,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 14659,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:05:12.543140Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T15:39:51.279106Z",
    "username": "user10",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 14659,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 7182,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 4,
    "percentageHours": 1.017986111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 12,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 1.0175
  },
  {
    "id": 6415608216,
    "task_id": 110169040,
    "user_id": 1476078,
    "keyboard": 23401,
    "mouse": 51185,
    "input_tracked": 99108,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 99108,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T06:17:26.341286Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T02:03:01.258835Z",
    "username": "user11",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 99108,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 67332,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 28,
    "percentageHours": 6.882499999999999,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 17,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 6,
    "percentActivityW": 48,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 6.885
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711920,
    "task_id": 111299925,
    "user_id": 1762379,
    "keyboard": 9260,
    "mouse": 27177,
    "input_tracked": 63034,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63034,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:55.058824Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:09.826018Z",
    "username": "user12",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63034,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 33416,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.377361111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 13,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 40,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.3774999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6438388730,
    "task_id": 111271635,
    "user_id": 1763812,
    "keyboard": 8023,
    "mouse": 34217,
    "input_tracked": 60716,
    "manual": 3056,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 63772,
    "created_at": "2022-09-04T06:11:14.526669Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:10.753741Z",
    "username": "user13",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 63772,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 39685,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.4286111111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 16,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 66,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4275
  },
  {
    "id": 6436711572,
    "task_id": 110962406,
    "user_id": 1512574,
    "keyboard": 13031,
    "mouse": 29149,
    "input_tracked": 58021,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 58021,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:37:32.555344Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-04T11:00:12.010515Z",
    "username": "user14",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 58021,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 35912,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 16,
    "percentageHours": 4.0292361111111115,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 15,
    "rolTittle": "DEV",
    "rolPriority": 0,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 46,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.0275
  },
  {
    "id": 6429845321,
    "task_id": 111275770,
    "user_id": 1597423,
    "keyboard": 7547,
    "mouse": 16932,
    "input_tracked": 45344,
    "manual": 9000,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 45344,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:02:22.445061Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T21:05:15.892875Z",
    "username": "user15",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 54344,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 21515,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 15,
    "percentageHours": 3.773888888888889,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 10,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 32,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.7724999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6429886569,
    "task_id": 111300959,
    "user_id": 1005008,
    "keyboard": 9124,
    "mouse": 23219,
    "input_tracked": 47335,
    "manual": 16930,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64265,
    "created_at": "2022-09-02T15:10:49.050765Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-02T15:37:15.995376Z",
    "username": "user16",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64265,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 30503,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.462847222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 47,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.4625
  },
  {
    "id": 6418406327,
    "task_id": 110056072,
    "user_id": 1005014,
    "keyboard": 3338,
    "mouse": 24665,
    "input_tracked": 51343,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 51343,
    "created_at": "2022-09-01T15:01:36.521321Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-01T15:35:14.010868Z",
    "username": "user17",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 51343,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 27397,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 14,
    "percentageHours": 3.565486111111111,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 13,
    "rolTittle": "SAC",
    "rolPriority": 1,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 62,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 3.5649999999999995
  },
  {
    "id": 6436728901,
    "task_id": 109755222,
    "user_id": 1846477,
    "keyboard": 9644,
    "mouse": 25906,
    "input_tracked": 64724,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 64724,
    "created_at": "2022-09-03T14:57:43.250737Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-09-03T19:24:22.872994Z",
    "username": "user18",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 44,
    "three_weekly_hours": 20,
    "summaryWeekly": 64724,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 29885,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 8,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 18,
    "percentageHours": 4.494722222222222,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 12,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 34,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 4.495
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 1886674,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user19",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 1931414,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user20",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  },
  {
    "id": null,
    "task_id": null,
    "user_id": 766827,
    "keyboard": 0,
    "mouse": 0,
    "input_tracked": 0,
    "manual": 0,
    "idle": 0,
    "resumed": 0,
    "billable": 0,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "username": "user21",
    "status": "active",
    "weekly_hours": 12.5,
    "three_weekly_hours": 7,
    "summaryWeekly": 0,
    "summaryoverallWeekly": 0,
    "dayliHoursDaily": 3,
    "summaryHoursTrackedWeekly": 0,
    "percentageHours": 0,
    "activityWeekly": 0,
    "percentageActivityWeekly": 0,
    "rolTittle": "DESIGN",
    "rolPriority": 2,
    "summaryStarts": 0,
    "percentActivityW": 0,
    "avergeHourWeekly": 0
  }
]

const maplabels = apidata.map(element => element.username);
const labels = maplabels;

// DataBar
const mapbarHorizontal = apidata.map(element => element.summaryHoursTrackedWeekly);
const barHorizontal = mapbarHorizontal;
// console.log('labels', barHorizontal);

// LineBar
const maplineBar = apidata.map(element => element.percentActivityW);
const lineBar = maplineBar;

// BarWeeklyHour Colaborador
const mapColbWeekly = apidata.map(element => element.three_weekly_hours);
const colbWeekly = mapColbWeekly;

const subLabels = {
  id: 'subLabels',
  afterDatasetsDraw(chart, args, pluginOptions) {
    const {
      ctx,
      chartArea: {
        left,
        right,
        top,
        bottom,
        width,
        height
      }
    } = chart;

    ctx.save();
    subLabelText('DEV', width / 4 * 1.5);
    subLabelText('SAC', width / 4 * 3.1);
    subLabelText('DESIGN', width / 4 * 3.7);

    function subLabelText(text, x) {
      ctx.font = 'bold 12px sans-serif';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText(text, x + left, bottom + 144);
      let xAxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      let xCenter = (xAxis.left + xAxis.right) / 1.45;
      let yBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
      [xAxis.left, xCenter, xAxis.right].forEach(x => {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x, yBottom);
        ctx.lineTo(x, yBottom + 110);
        ctx.stroke();
      });

      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'lightgray';
      ctx.moveTo(width / 4 * 3.45, yBottom);
      ctx.lineTo(width / 4 * 3.45, yBottom + 110);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.restore();
    }



  }
}


const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("chart"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
        type: 'line',
        label: '% ACTIVITY',
        backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
        borderColor: '#FF7605',
        data: lineBar,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'start',
          align: 'center',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#FF7605',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'WEEKLY SUMMARY OF HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#222A35',
        borderColor: '#222A35',
        data: barHorizontal,
        datalabels: {
          rotation: 270,
          padding: 10
        }

      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: 'HOURS',
        backgroundColor: '#008582',
        borderColor: '#008582',
        data: colbWeekly,
        datalabels: {
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'top',
          clamp: true,
          backgroundColor: '#008582',
          color: 'white',
          font: {
            weight: 'bold'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        color: 'white',
        font: {
          weight: 'bold'
        },
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'AVERAGE WEEKLY HOURS'
      }
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      'x-axis-0': {
        stacked: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 80,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 20,
          minRotation: 90
        },
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      'y-axis-0': {
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [subLabels]
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.0.0/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@2.0.0"></script>
  <canvas id="chart" height="200"></canvas>
</body>
```

Saludos Cordiales.